# Query Mysql com diversas tabelas

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou com problemas para realizar um select em algumas tabelas, eu fiz o seguinte.

tenho 5 tabelas (modulo,componentes,etapa,imagens,registros)

a tabela registros só recebe ID'S das outras tabelas , ela unifica os registros na verdade,

o que eu preciso fazer é buscar os registros das outras tabelas baseado nos iD'S que estão na tabela registro. eu tentei fazer assim mas está me retornando valores repetidos.

```
SELECT modulo.nome_modulo,modulo.indice,modulo.revisao,componentes.codigo,componentes.local,etapa.etapa,componentes.quantidade,imagens.imagem FROM registros
INNER JOIN etapa ON etapa.id_etapa= registros.id_etapa
INNER JOIN componentes ON  componentes.id_componente = registros.id_componente
INNER JOIN imagens ON  imagens.id_componente = registros.id_imagem
INNER JOIN modulo ON modulo.id_modulo = registros.id_modulo

WHERE.....
```

Sou iniciante, não sei se isso é possível ou tão pouco se essa era a melhor maneira de fazer isso.

Comment: Na quarta linha não deveria ser `INNER JOIN imagens ON  imagens.id_imagem = registros.id_imagem` em vez de `INNER JOIN imagens ON  imagens.id_componente = registros.id_imagem`

Comment: Vlw brother , era isso mesmo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faz assim, na tabela principal você tem o id do usuário, nas outras tabelas você faz um campo com o nome idcli, na hora do insert, esse idcli recebe o id do usuário da tabela principal, então para recuperar você faz:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "db");

$id = $_POST['id'];

if ($sth = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM suaTabela WHERE idcli='$id'")){
    while ($row = $sth->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['nome'];

    }
}

if ($sth = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM suaTabela2 WHERE idcli='$id'")){
    while ($row = $sth->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['nome2'];

    }
}
```

E assim por diante

Answer (score 0):

Bem não sei exatamente como suas tabelas estão, mas eu mudaria a query para o seguinte, apenas colocando `()` e um `DISTINCT` para uma melhor organização:

```
SELECT DISTINCT modulo.nome_modulo,modulo.indice,modulo.revisao,componentes.codigo,compone
ntes.local,etapa.etapa,componentes.quantidade,imagens.imagem FROM 
((((registros
INNER JOIN etapa ON etapa.id_etapa= registros.id_etapa)
INNER JOIN componentes ON  componentes.id_componente = registros.id_componente)
INNER JOIN imagens ON  imagens.id_imagem = registros.id_imagem)
INNER JOIN modulo ON modulo.id_modulo = registros.id_modulo)
```

E também acho que na linha 4 você acabou esquecendo de colocar `imagens.id_imagem`